# Java based SIP endpoint

Tags: java, sip, voip, jain-sip

I am looking to implement a sip endpoint using java.

I came across jain-sip. But, it's not clear whether it's used to implement a sip client or sip endpoint itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to implement any sip endpoint with jain-sip. It is used in user agents, servers, b2buas, proxies, sbcs and registrars. But if you need something beyond the SIP such as media/RTP then you need additional RTP or relay stack.

Comment: These examples cover all the base sip rfc role cases https://github.com/usnistgov/jsip/tree/master/src/examples but let me know if you are looking for something more specific.